# LabVIEW call library node error 1097 for c++ dll

Tags: c++, labview

I have a c++ library that I'm calling via the standard call library node in LabVIEW. I'm using 2017 VS to edit the c source files and 2020 32 bit version of LabVIEW. Consequently I've made sure to build new versions of my library in x86. I have not been able to nail down why I keep getting a 1097 error after the node call (I've included pictures of the function prototype that I'm attempting to call in the c header file, the node configuration interface, as well as a picture of the block diagram).

Additionally, LabVIEW reported these errors in the log when I restarted my development system:

***DWarn 0x0E697B77: Caught exception in ExtCode call!***

***DWarn 0x50CBD7C1: Got corruption with error 1097 calling library Multilane_ML4039_Interface.dll function GetEyeDimensions***

I've read that with this combination of errors, LabVIEW is catching an exception thrown by the .dll and this will prompt the library node to generator error 1097. This is often because of improperly configured parameters but as far as I can tell, my configuration is ok.

Any help is much appreciated.

[Function prototype in .h file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJoRp.png)

[Library configure node in LabVIEW](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGaoC.png)

[Block diagram containing library node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIVZk.png)

Answer (score 0):

Got it resolved. My tired eyes didn't see I had one of my parameters in the prototype entered as a pointer instead of a value. Check those parameters people!